# java program that allows the user to enter a number of columns and rows of panels with a loop but can't figure out the error

Tags: java, swing, awt

This code was shown in my textbook but the following code seems to have errors when I compile it.

```
Color backColor = Color(red,green,blue);
ColorPanel panel = new ColorPanel(backColor);
pane.add(panel);
```

Here's the whole code:

```
import javax.swing.*; 

import java.awt.*; 
import java.util.Random; 
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class GUIWindow { 
    public static void main(String [] args){ 
        JFrame theGUI = new JFrame(); 
        theGUI.setTitle("GUI Example"); 
        String inputStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number of rows", "5"); 
        if( inputStr ==null ) return; 
        int rows = Integer.parseInt(inputStr); 
        String inputStr1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number of columns", "5"); 
        if(inputStr1 == null)return; 
        int cols = Integer.parseInt(inputStr1); 
        theGUI.setSize(cols*5, rows*5); 
        theGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFram... 
        Container pane = theGUI.getContentPane(); 
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows,cols)); 
        Random gen = new Random(); 
        for(int i =1; i<= rows*cols; i++){ 
            int red = gen.nextInt(256); 
            int green = gen.nextInt(256);   
            int blue = gen.nextInt(256); 
            Color backColor = new Color(red,green,blue); 
            ColorPanel panel = new ColorPanel(backColor); 
            pane.add (panel); 
        } 
        theGUI.setVisible(true); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Color backColor = Color(red,green,blue);
ColorPanel panel = new ColorPanel(backColor);
pane.add(panel);

Comment: That's code, not an error. Please copy-paste the actual error message you are getting.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia color panel cannot be resolved to a type is the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't import `ColorPanel` which is not a standard swing class, you must add the correct import, something like (**but `com.some.package` name correct**):

```
import com.some.package.ColorPanel;
```

Only reference swing-related I've found is [`bycom.esri.arcgis.beans.ui.ColorPanel`](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/beans/ui/ColorPanel.html), this class extends `javax.swing.JPanel` but not sure if is what you need or if you created your own.

As long as your comment says:

> @FastSnail: did you create a class named "ColorPanel" ?
>   @Ayah Al-Harthy: no it wasn't on the textbook

And looking to the code, you can use `JPanel` with `setBackground(Color)` to do same stuff (I guess). Using [`Color(int,int,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int,%20int,%20int)) constructor.

```
Color backColor = new Color(red,green,blue);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBackground(backColor);
// set some dimensions if necessary before adding
panel.add(panel);
```

---

Also note this line is incomplete:

```
theGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFram...
```

Comment: but the color panel was i will try it out

Comment: @AyahAl-Harthy did you create  a class named "ColorPanel" ?

Comment: @FastSnail no it wasn't on the textbook

Comment: do u think its the for loop thats causing the problem I'm new in java so I'm just guessing

Comment: @AyahAl-Harthy, nope, I think problem is not the `for-loop`, check my update to see if it works with `JPanel`

Comment: i did it gave me a new error
The method Color(int, int, int) is undefined for the type GUIWindow

Comment: @JordiCastilla its pane.add (panel) on the book why should in be "panel.add" and for the "int alpha=100" shouldn't be int alpha = gen.nextInt(256) because of the Random gen = new Random code.